# R - Fill columns in df

Tags: r, fill, na

```
                a                      b                  P116 P127 P125 P107 P101 P220 P135                                 
1 P116,P115,P113,P120,P112,  P128,P125,P127,P123,P126,    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
2 P116,P115,P113,P120,P112,  P128,P125,P127,P123,P126,    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 
3 P120,P117,P116,P115,P119,      P98,P94,P96,P99,P93,     NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
4      P34,P36,P40,P39,P37,  P108,P106,P107,P110,P109,    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
5 P123,P127,P125,P118,P198,  P135,P132,P134,P138,P131,    NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
6 P142,P148,P149,P140,P150,      P80,P81,P89,P87,P86,     NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

I've got a data frame where some values from columns a and b matches names of other columns. I want to replace NA's with numbers:
1(if value in row of column "a" matches name of columns 3:9), 0(if values in columns "a", "b" don't match names of columns 3:9), -1(if value in row of column "b" matches name of columns 3:9)

It should look like this.

```
              a                          b               P116 P127 P125 P107 P101 P220 P135                          
1 P116,P115,P113,P120,P112,  P128,P125,P127,P123,P126,    1    -1   -1   0    0    0    0
2 P116,P115,P113,P120,P112,  P128,P125,P127,P123,P126,    1    -1   -1   0    0    0    0 
3 P120,P117,P116,P115,P119,      P98,P94,P96,P99,P93,     1     0    0   0    0    0    0
4      P34,P36,P40,P39,P37,  P108,P106,P107,P110,P109,    0     0    0  -1    0    0    0
5 P123,P127,P125,P118,P198,  P135,P132,P134,P138,P131,    0     1    1   0    0    0   -1
6 P142,P148,P149,P140,P150,      P80,P81,P89,P87,P86,     0     0    0   0    0    0    0
```

Comment: What happens if both columns "a" and "b" match?

Comment: It's not happening in this data frame.

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
df[-(1:2)] <- Reduce(`+`,Map(`*`, lapply(c("a", "b"), function(nm) 
       do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(df[[nm]], ","), function(x)
         +(names(df)[-(1:2)] %in% x)))), c(1, -1)))
 df
 #                          a                         b P116 P127 P125 P107 P101 P220 P135
 #1 P116,P115,P113,P120,P112, P128,P125,P127,P123,P126,    1   -1   -1    0    0    0    0
 #2 P116,P115,P113,P120,P112, P128,P125,P127,P123,P126,    1   -1   -1    0    0    0    0
 #3 P120,P117,P116,P115,P119,      P98,P94,P96,P99,P93,    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
 #4      P34,P36,P40,P39,P37, P108,P106,P107,P110,P109,    0    0    0   -1    0    0    0
 #5 P123,P127,P125,P118,P198, P135,P132,P134,P138,P131,    0    1    1    0    0    0   -1
 #6 P142,P148,P149,P140,P150,      P80,P81,P89,P87,P86,    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not tested it properly and it's likely to be slow on larger datasets, but here's my very un-R-like attempt:

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
    for (col in 3:ncol(df)) {
        if (grepl(colnames(df)[col], df[row, "a"])) {
            df[row, col] <- 1
        } else if (grepl(colnames(df)[col], df[row, "b"])) {
            df[row, col] <- -1
        } else {
            df[row, col] <- 0
        }
    }
}
```

This loops through and uses `grepl` to return a logical match if the string in `a` or `b` is a match for the column name.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tested functional approach.

Given your data frame:

```
df=data.frame(a=c(
    "P116,P115,P113,P120,P112,", 
    "P116,P115,P113,P120,P112,", 
    "P120,P117,P116,P115,P119,", 
    "     P34,P36,P40,P39,P37,", 
    "P123,P127,P125,P118,P198,", 
    "P142,P148,P149,P140,P150,"    
  ),
  b=c(
    "P128,P125,P127,P123,P126,", 
    "P128,P125,P127,P123,P126,", 
    "     P98,P94,P96,P99,P93,", 
    "P108,P106,P107,P110,P109,", 
    "P135,P132,P134,P138,P131,",    
    "     P80,P81,P89,P87,P86," 
  ),    
  P116=NA, P127=NA, P125=NA, P107=NA, P101=NA, P220=NA, P135=NA,
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The solution is:

```
sel=lapply(as.list(df[, 1:2]), function(col)
    t(sapply(col, function(x) match(strsplit(x, "," )[[1]], names(df)[-(1:2)], nomatch=0))))
dfm=as.matrix(df[, -(1:2)])
k=-1
lapply(sel, function(selr){
    i<<-0;  k<<-k*-1
    apply(selr, 1, function(j) {
        i <<- i+1
        dfm[cbind(i,j)]<<- k
    })}
    )
dfm[is.na(dfm)]=0     
df[, -(1:2)]=dfm
```

You get:

```
df
                            a                         b  P116 P127 P125 P107 P101 P220 P135  
## 1 P116,P115,P113,P120,P112, P128,P125,P127,P123,P126,    1   -1   -1    0    0    0    0 
## 2 P116,P115,P113,P120,P112, P128,P125,P127,P123,P126,    1   -1   -1    0    0    0    0 
## 3 P120,P117,P116,P115,P119,      P98,P94,P96,P99,P93,    1    0    0    0    0    0    0 
## 4      P34,P36,P40,P39,P37, P108,P106,P107,P110,P109,    0    0    0   -1    0    0    0 
## 5 P123,P127,P125,P118,P198, P135,P132,P134,P138,P131,    0    1    1    0    0    0   -1 
## 6 P142,P148,P149,P140,P150,      P80,P81,P89,P87,P86,    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Please, next time use `dput(<your dataframe>)` to make your question simpler to answer.